# Calculating probability using Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

In a computer game, if the player wins a game, the probability that he will win the next game is 0.9. If the player loses the game, the probability that he will win the game is 0.4. Consider 'win' and 'lose' as the states of a two-state Markov chain.

1. Write down the one-step transition probability matrix.
2. Player consecutively plays three games. If he wins the first game, find the probability that the player wins the third game.

I am new to this subject can you please help me to do this sum?
 so far I have constructed the transition matrix

\begin{bmatrix} 0.9 & 0.1 & \\\ 0.4 & 0.6  \end{bmatrix}

This is what my idea on the 2nd part of question.
Since player has won the 1st game, we can use upper half of the matrix to multiply  the original matrix to find the probability of winning the 3rd game

$ i.e $ \begin{bmatrix} 0.9 & 0.1 &  \end{bmatrix}X\begin{bmatrix} 0.9 & 0.1 & \\\ 0.4 & 0.6  \end{bmatrix}
So it would yield the answer as 0.81+0.04 = 0.85

Is this method correct?

Comment: A good way to check is to simply enumerate the paths.  There are only two, namely $WWW,WLW$.  $P(WWW)=.9^2, P(WLW)=.1\times.4$.  Thus the probability of winning the third is the sum $.81+.04=.85$, so you're looking good.

Comment: Thank you for sorting it out :)

Comment: Actually, you are (rightfully) computing $P(WWW\mid W**)$ and $P(WLW\mid W**)$, not $P(WWW)$ and $P(WLW)$.